# readAsBinaryString() not working properly

Tags: javascript, filereader

This is my code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    download(reader.result, "Test.stl");
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(input_file_field.files[0]);
```

Result file:

[image: Result file]

Original file:

[image: Original file]

The output is almost the same with little differences (and this is not a problem of the "download" function, is the same if I put a log into the console).

Any ideas of what's happening?

---

**Edit:**

This is the code I'm using for the binary conversion (not working neither):

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var fileData = reader.result;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(fileData);
    var binaryText = '';

    for (var index = 0; index < bytes.byteLength; index++) {
        binaryText += String.fromCharCode(bytes[index]);
    }

    download(binaryText, "Test.stl");
}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(input_field.files[0]);
```

Comment: From MDN's page on [`readAsBinaryString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString): *Note that this method is now deprecated as per the 12 July 2012 Working Draft from the W3C.* And *This method has been removed from the FileAPI standard. FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer() should be used instead.*... So, maybe that?

Comment: What is `MIME` type  setting at text editor? Why do you not use `.readAsText()`?

Comment: Using `readAsText` led to the same result: the file is corrupted. I also tried utilizing `readAsArrayBuffer` and then converting to a Uint8Array but I have the same output as with `readAsBinaryString`.

Comment: Can you run [this test](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/2LvcLLx3/) for us? Load the STL file, save it back to disk with correct extension, compare in a hex viewer, is the problem still there? This is as short circuit as it gets.

Comment: @K3N I've updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2LvcLLx3/2/). That code is working - the downloaded file is exactly the same as the input file.

Comment: @fsinisi90 ok, lets see if we can eliminate FileReader and a binary chain: how will this variant work: https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/2LvcLLx3/3/ ? (I used my original fiddle as I had it handy)

Comment: @K3N that code is also working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the file as ArrayBuffer the content will be in binary format (as a raw byte array).

This line:

```
binaryText += String.fromCharCode(bytes[index]);
```

can however mess up things as any values outside the ASCII range (0-127) is subject to 16-bit unicode encoding (UTF-16/USC-2), and the original byte may end up using two chars to represent the source value.

You can see for example where the first difference occur at position 0x55, the byte value 0xB3 (179 in decimal) and outside the ASCII-range, becomes 0xC2B3. The next value 0xEF (239 in decimal) becomes 0xC3AF, then the next 0x3E is kept since it is < 128, and so forth.

However, there is no good reason to go through this conversion step though as the data is already in binary format. The entire loop can (and should) be removed.

Simply assign a view to the ArrayBuffer (as you do before the conversion step) and use that to read the data via index/position.

If you intend to parse the format I would recommend using a DataView instead of Uint8Array as files tend to define variable widths of data fields, and a DataView is more flexible and handy in those situations.

If it's for transferring to server/store for download, you can simply keep the original File blob and send that pretty much as-is (see the first [test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/2LvcLLx3/)).